# How to unpack lists in 2 for loops?

Tags: python, regex, list, for-loop

I'm trying to unpack 2 lists in 2 for loops without repeating the item. For example:

```
list1 = re.compile('postHeader.+?href="(.+?)".+?>(.+?)<.+?src=.+? src="(.+?)"', re.DOTALL).findall(html)
list2 = re.findall('<p>Links.(+?)</p>', html)
    for item1, item2, item3 in list1:
        for item4 in list2:
            print item1, item2, item3, item4
```

The result I get is:
Item1, item2, item3, item4 then item1 (previous), item2 (previous), item3 (previous), item4 (changes) then item1 (previous)... Item1 repeats 4 times while item4 continuously changes going in a sequence which is what I want. How do I get it all in sync?

Comment: can you explain what are trying to achieve.?

Comment: You are looking for `zip`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the builtin `zip` function.

```
>>> list1 = [(10, 11, 12), (13, 14, 15)]
>>> list2 = [20, 21]
>>> 
>>> for (item1, item2, item3), item4 in zip(list1, list2):
...     print item1, item2, item3, item4
... 
10 11 12 20
13 14 15 21
```

Comment: @Dzrte4gle no problem. Consider accepting the answer, please.